# How can I sort a 2D vector based on the values of another vector?

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a 2D vector containing the grades of the students and the university they will attend.

```
vector <vector<int> > results {{170,65,78,93,80,12},{6,3,8,9,1,1}}
```

It is known that there are no common grades, but the universities can be the same. In the example above, the person with 170 will go to university 6, the person with 65 will go to university 3 etc. The number of grades is always the same as the number of universities. I also have a 1D vector of the grades in the order that they have to be presented. For example:

```
vector<int> backup {12,93,80,170,65,78}
```

I have to print out the elements of the second row of the 2D vector in accordance with the backup. In this specific example the output would be:
1, 9, 1, 6, 3, 8
This is because 12 for example is the 2D vector corresponds to 1, and 12 is first in the backup, so 1 will be the first output. I have tried doing this:

```
vector<int>::iterator it;
ptrdiff_t pos;

for(i=0; i < backup.size(); i++)
{
    it = find(results[0].begin(), results[0].end(), backup[i]);
    pos = distance(results[0].begin(), it);
    fprintf(output, "%d\n",results[1][pos]);
}
```

but the problem is that the execution time for a large file takes almost half a second. This project is for a competition where execution time plays a paramount role. Do you have an efficient way to propose that can help me solve my problem (in under 90 ms)?

Edit: This currently has 400 ms

Comment: Step one: enable your compilers optimizer and build a release version of your code rather than the default debug build.

Comment: Your 2D vector is an `std::unordered_map` with extra steps. It *could* be faster than your code (or could not, no way to check except for testing both).

Comment: @JesperJuhl have to submit the .cp file

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I tried the unordered map and it is unbelievably faster. Thanks a lot! I think I have found the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Build a hash map(unordered map) or an ordered map from `results` vector. Now iterate through `backup` and using the grade value from `backup`, retrieve its corresponding university from map. Complexity would be `O(NlogN)`(ordered map) or `O(N)`(on average using unordered map), where `N` is the length of the backup array or `results[0].size()` (since it's of same length). Complexity of your current approach is `O(N*(N+N)) ==> O(N^2)`.

Comment: @AjayDabas That's what I did. The execution time is a lot, a lot slower. Thanks for being so helpful. I don't understand what this complexity is though, could you elaborate(I am 14 so still a rookie)

Comment: You may need to learn complexity theory in order to understand this so you can skip this for the time being if you want, or learn theory and come back to understand it. A comment is too short to explain the whole concept here. :)

Comment: @AjayDabas Ok thank you a lot. I will look it up!